# 3D Plane with labels

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hello I've been trying to look around for 3d plane like this and no idea how I can make it.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Welcome! There are several possibilities. Apart from `tikz-3dplot` you can just use the perspective library.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={30}{45},line cap=round,>=stealth,
 dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
 \draw(0,0,0) coordinate[dot,label=below:$A$] (A) 
    -- (0,2,0) coordinate[label=left:$B$] (B)
    -- (2,2,0) coordinate[label=right:$C$] (C)
    -- (2,0,0) coordinate[label=right:$D$] (D)-- cycle;
 \draw[->]  (A) -- node[left]{$e_1$} (B) ;
 \draw[->]  (A) -- node[below]{$e_2$} (D) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can then install a perspective view, e.g.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{perspective}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[3d view={30}{45},line cap=round,>=stealth,
 dot/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt},perspective={p={(5,0,0)}}]
 \draw (tpp cs:x=0,y=0,z=0) coordinate[dot,label=below:$A$] (A) 
    -- (tpp cs:x=0,y=2,z=0) coordinate[label=left:$B$] (B)
    -- (tpp cs:x=2,y=2,z=0) coordinate[label=right:$C$] (C)
    -- (tpp cs:x=2,y=0,z=0) coordinate[label=right:$D$] (D)-- cycle;
 \draw[->]  (A) -- node[left]{$e_1$} (B) ;
 \draw[->]  (A) -- node[below]{$e_2$} (D) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that compared to the first example

- the perspective key got added (with just `p` different from its default, but you can also change `q` and `r`),
- each coordinate is now of the form `(tpp cs:x=<x>,y=<y>,z=<z>)` instead of just `(<x>,<y>,<z>)`.

For more details, please consult section **64 Three Point Perspective Drawing Library** of pgfmanual v3.1.5.